# Eclipse crashes when it's starting

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

I try to launch my Eclipse, it starts window with logo but while loading workbench it crashes.

Log is very long, so I put a link: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=TXieq

Comment: Looks like some internal class was not found. Maybe your installation got corrupted? Try re-installing ADT.

Comment: Eclipse worked before crash. I installed it 2,5 months ago and worked with him.

Comment: I agree.  Every exception there is saying there's a problem with ADT.  I'd re-install ADT.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Visit [developer.android.com][1] and download the latest sdk.
2. 2.Select the type of Operating System-32/64 bit accept the license agreement
       and download.
3. After that update the packages in the SDK Manager

   [1]: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html