# How can I re-install ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have Eclipse and ADT. My copy of Eclipse crashed. In this topic ([Eclipse crashes when it's starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861843/eclipse-crashes-when-its-starting)) I was advised to re-install ADT. I read that I can install ADT from Eclipse. But my Eclipse doesn't start. Do I have to re-install Eclipse too?

Answer (score 1):

Hi found solution by myself after doing some research,

- Go to eclipse home folder.
- search for 'anndroid' -> In windows 7 you can use search bar
- delete all the file related to android, which is shown in the results.
- restart the eclipse.
- Install the ADT plugin again and Restart plugin

Now everything works fine.

Comment: I re-download Eclipse and now it's ok)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, one does not simply reinstall `Eclipse`. You just need to redownload it and replace the old version with this one. Then you just follow the tutorial on [Android Develper](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) and tell the installer where your Android SDK is located (don't need to download it again). At least that is what I do when I need to fix some `Eclipse + ADT Plugin` problems or update `Eclipse`